# Android SimpleCursorTreeAdapter with Loader

Tags: android, expandablelistview, simplecursoradapter

Am using `Loader` with `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`  to fetch data from D.B. and displaying them in different groups inside ExpendableListView.

my delemma is which approach should I take:

1. create loader for every group in the ExpendableListView
2. create just one loader and handle the logic by myself

what is your suggestion ?